# CSVLayer as a source for Search widget in ArcGIS Javascript

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, csv, search, widget

I am trying to add my CSVLayer as a source for the Search widget, however, I've been unsuccessful.  My Search widget searches addresses and I was able to add one of the sources from this example (https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/search_multiplesources.html) successfully, however my CSVLayer doesn't return any results in the Search widget.

Has anyone had any success or experience with adding a CSVLayer as a source for the Search widget in ArcGIS Javascript?  Below is a code snippet...

```
var csv = new CSVLayer("file.csv", {
      outFields: ["*"]
    });
var search = new Search({
      enableButtonMode: false,
      enableLabel: false,
      enableInfoWindow: true,
      showInfoWindowOnSelect: false,
      map: map
    }, "search");

    var sources = search.get("sources");

    sources.push({
      featureLayer: csv,
      searchFields: ["Name"],
      displayField: "Name",
      exactMatch: false,
      outFields: ["*"],
      name: "Foo",
      placeholder: "FooPlace",
      maxResults: 6,
      maxSuggestions: 6,

      infoTemplate: template,
      enableSuggestions: true,
      minCharacters: 0
    });
```

Could the issue be that my csv var is technically a CSVLayer and not a FeatureLayer?

Comment: Are you receiving an error or just not receiving expected results?

Comment: No error and my Foo layer even shows in the Search drop-down but when i search on Foo Place I get no results so it seems that the Search widget isn't actually reading the CSVLayer.  My CSVLayer displays in my map with no issue, and my InfoTemplate works as well.

Comment: If you are not joining the CSV to anything spatial, a spatial tool is not going to find it.

Comment: I'm mapping the var csv, points on a map based on the latitude and longitude columns in the file.csv.

Comment: can you post your csv file please, or at least and excerpt. do the standard check for field names being nothing out of ordinary, and try to avoid null values and that there's no syntax errors (commas missing or similar)

Comment: longitude,latitude,Name,Address,Address2,City,State,Zip,Status,Health,CPU_Use
-79,38,Place1,1234 Elm Street,,Your Town,Your State,12345,Online,75,75

Those are my headers and an example row.  I am able to map the CSVLayer with no problem, I am also able to reference the column/field names in my InfoTemplate for the popup in my new viewer.  The issue is with Search.  I suspect that the issue is Search may not be able to get a CSVLayer as a source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the API reference:

> The Search widget provides a way to perform search capabilities based on locator service(s) and/or map/feature service feature layer(s)

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/search-amd.html

As you speculated in your own question, a `CSVlayer` is not one of the widget's supported inputs.